# inverting dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary

```
{'jackie chan': ('rush hour', 'rush hour 2'), 
 'crish tucker': ('rush hour', 'rush    hour 2')}
```

I want the inverse dictionary to be

```
{'rush hour': ('jackie chan', 'crish tucker'), 
 'rush hour 2': ('jackie chan', 'crish tucker')}
```

I already got the function to inverse but it doesn't look like the second dictionary

```
def invert_actor_dict(actor_dict):
    movie_dict = {}
    for key,value in actor_dict.iteritems():

        for actor in value:
            if actor in movie_dict:
                movie_dict[actor].append(key)
            else:
                movie_dict[actor] = (key)
    return movie_dict
```

Comment: Chris Tucker would probably take issue with how you spelled his name.

Comment: And how you spelled the second film. Or do you want the additional white space to be removed?

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do this with [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
def invert_dict(d):
    inverted_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for actor, movies in d.iteritems():
        for movie in movies:
            inverted_dict.add(actor)
    return inverted_dict
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code has two problems

The **first problem** you have is at these lines:

```
if actor in movie_dict:
    movie_dict[actor].append(key)
else:
    movie_dict[actor] = (key)
```

When you write `movie_dict[actor] = (key)`, you are not creating a tuple - the parenthesis are just for precedence. To create a tuple, you would have to add a comma at the end:

```
 movie_dict[actor] = (key,)
```

Anyway, this will not work as well, because tuples are immutable. You should either use a list:

```
if actor in movie_dict:
    movie_dict[actor].append(key)
else:
    movie_dict[actor] = [key] # Square brackets
```

or create new tuples:

```
if actor in movie_dict:
    movie_dict[actor] = movie_dict[actor] + (key,)
else:
    movie_dict[actor] = (key,)
```

I strongly suggest you to use the first option. If you *really* need to use tuples, convert the lists to tuples after the processing.

The **second problem** is that you seem to expect

```
'rush hour 2'
```

to be equal to

```
'rush    hour 2'
```

as seen in the dictionary:

```
{'jackie chan': 
    ('rush hour', 'rush hour 2'), 
 'crish tucker': 
    ('rush hour', 'rush    hour 2')}
```

But this is not true:

```
>>> 'rush hour 2' == 'rush    hour 2'
False
```

How could you solve it? Well, the simplest solution I devise is to split the string at spaces and then rejoin it with only one space:

```
def invert_actor_dict(actor_dict):
    movie_dict = {}
    for key,value in actor_dict.iteritems():
        for actor in value:
            split_movie_name = key.split()
            # 'rush     hour 2'.split() == ['rush', 'hour', '2']
            movie_name = " ".join(split_movie_name)
            # " ".join(['rush', 'hour', '2']) == 'rush hour 2'
            if actor in movie_dict:
                movie_dict[actor].append(movie_name)
            else:
                movie_dict[actor] = [movie_name]
    return movie_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def invert_actor_dict(actor_dict):
   movie_dict = {}
   for actor,movies in actor_dict.iteritems(): 

       for movie in movies:
           if not movie_dict.has(movie):
               movie_dict[movie]=[]
           movie_dict[movie].append(actor)
   return movie_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'jackie chan': ('rush hour', 'rush hour 2'), 'crish tucker': ('rush hour', 'rush hour 2')}
h = dict()

for actor, films in d.items():
    for film in films:
        if not film in h:
            h[film] = list()
        h[film].append(actor)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'rush hour': ('jackie chan', 'crish tucker'), 'rush hour 2': ('jackie chan', 'crish tucker')}

result = {}

for film, names in d.items():
    for name in names:
        if not name in result:
            result[name] = set([film])
        else:
            result[name].add(film)

print result
```

**Result:**

```
{'crish tucker': set(['rush hour', 'rush hour 2']), 'jackie chan': set(['rush hour', 'rush hour 2'])}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem you have is you're using (key) to represent a list, which should be [key].

```
def invert_actor_dict(actor_dict):
    movie_dict = {}
    for key,value in actor_dict.iteritems():

        for actor in value:
            if actor in movie_dict:
                movie_dict[actor].append(key)
            else:
                movie_dict[actor] = (key)
    return movie_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very convenient [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method in a `dict` object. With using it, the code simplifies to the following:

```
d = {'rush hour': ('jackie chan', 'crish tucker'), 'rush hour 2': ('jackie chan', 'crish tucker')}

result = {}

for film, names in d.items():
    for name in names:
        result.setdefault(name,set([])).add(film)

print result
```

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary is by default not not sortable, so you can not sort it. You can look into the structure [ordered dictionary](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html) if the order matters